# how to pass kwargs in ajax urls in django? Reverse for '' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern tried: ['partners/analytics/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I have the following code in one of my templates:

```
      var id = "{{a.id}}";

$.ajax({
                url :'{% url 'this:dashboard' id %}',,
                type : 'POST',
                data : {
                    

                },      
            });
```

I get the following error?

```
Reverse for '' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dash/here/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

my url is:

```
    path('here/<int:id>/', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
url :'{% url 'this:dashboard' id %}',,
```

To

```
url :'{% url 'this:dashboard' a.id %}',
```

The issue with your code is, the templates are rendered in the server and the `var id` gets its value only after being executed in the client slide that's why you are getting URL error.